# Insert array value on string php

Tags: php

I'm getting an error trying to make this

```
$array = array("text");

echo "text $array['0']";
```

it's possible to make it shis way instead  concatenate

```
echo "text ".$array['0'];
```

Comment: `echo "text ".$array['0'];` should work

Comment: Or enclose your array element in `{ }` - `echo "text {$array['0']}";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***1.*** You need to remove `'` around `0`

```
echo "text $array[0]";
```

Output:- https://eval.in/993458

***2.Or*** enclose array element with `{}`

```
echo "text {$array['0']}";
```

Output:-https://eval.in/993460

Answer (score 2):

remove single quotes `'` inside double quortes `"`,

```
echo "text $array[0]";
```

[Live Demo](https://eval.in/993448)

Comment: Always disliked the way PHP has these inconsistent ways of doing things.

Comment: This not inconsistency, how php know that, It is direct php variable or variable is used to mix with string. like these [exmaple1](https://eval.in/993498) and [example2](https://eval.in/993499)

Comment: If it's in ", miss out the ', if you miss out the ' when it isn't in " you get a notice (Use of undefined constant) if the index is non-numeric.  A few too many if's for me.

Comment: you can think about execution and conversion (like interpolation). any language uses the conversion before execution, and php  aslo does, it converts `["a"]` to `[a]` but if write `[a]` it treat as `constant` and convert with the constant value. so its depends how you write and how it convert before execution. Thanks for comment.